# How to use cast or another function to create a binary table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, casting, reshape

I am trying to create a list of factors that have a binary response and have been using cast.

```
DF2 <- cast(data.frame(DM), id ~ region)
names(DF2)[-1] <- paste("region", names(DF2)[-1], sep = "")
```

The problem I am getting is that the responses are the frequency of which the answer comes up, while I'm looking for just whether or not it matches.

For example I have:

```
id region
 1   2
 1   3
 2   2
 3   1
 3   1
```

What I'd like is:

```
id region1 region2 region3
1   0          1     1
2   0          1     0
3   1          0     0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original data:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3), region=factor(c(2,3,2,1,1)))

> x
  id region
1  1      2
2  1      3
3  2      2
4  3      1
5  3      1
```

Group up the data:

```
aggregate(model.matrix(~ region - 1, data=x), x["id"], max)
```

Result:

```
  id region1 region2 region3
1  1       0       1       1
2  2       0       1       0
3  3       1       0       0
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an `aggregate` solution, but it wasn't coming to me. +1.

Comment: @mrdwab Don't worry, it took me 12 hours for it to click!

Answer (score 8):

I kind of prefer `dcast` from **reshape2**:

```
library(reshape2)
dat <- read.table(text = "id region
 1   2
 1   3
 2   2
 3   1
 3   1",header = TRUE,sep = "")

dcast(dat,id~region,fun.aggregate = function(x){as.integer(length(x) > 0)})

  id 1 2 3
1  1 0 1 1
2  2 0 1 0
3  3 1 0 0
```

There may be a smoother way to do that, but I'll be honest I don't cast stuff all that often.

Comment: I love the `reshape2` package, but sometimes things seem so slow. In comparison to your code, `(table(df) > 0)+0` is almost 24 times faster on my system! Specifying `value.var` usually speeds things up a little bit, but I wonder if there are any other tips on how to speed up `dcast`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's sort of a "tricky" way to do it in one line using `table` (the brackets are important). Assuming your `data.frame` is named `df`:

```
(table(df) > 0)+0
#    region
# id  1 2 3
#   1 0 1 1
#   2 0 1 0
#   3 1 0 0
```

`table(df) > 0` gives us `TRUE` and `FALSE`; adding `+0` converts the `TRUE` and `FALSE` to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

No specialized functions are needed:

```
x <- data.frame(id=1:4, region=factor(c(3,2,1,2)))
x
   id region
1  1      3
2  2      2
3  3      1
4  4      2

x.bin <- data.frame(x$id, sapply(levels(x$region), `==`, x$region))
names(x.bin) <- c("id", paste("region", levels(x$region),sep=''))
x.bin

  id region1 region2 region3
1  1   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
2  2   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
3  3    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
4  4   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
```

Or for integer results:

```
x.bin2 <- data.frame(x$id,  
    apply(sapply(levels(x$region), `==`, x$region),2,as.integer)
) 
names(x.bin2) <- c("id", paste("region", levels(x$region),sep=''))
x.bin2


  id region1 region2 region3
1  1       0       0       1
2  2       0       1       0
3  3       1       0       0
4  4       0       1       0
```