# Updating Variable using functions in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

This is a very quick question, I also asked a more complicated one in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140218/add-dummies-with-conditions-in-data-table/21141409?noredirect=1#comment31817772_21141409)

In this link, Roland kindly gave a very elegant solution to my problems. But I want to figure out why my solution doesn't work.

```
DT <- data.table(UID = paste0("UID",rep(1:5,each=2), 
  date = as.IDate("2012-01-01","2012-01-02","2012-01-03","2012-01-04","2012-01-05","2012-01-06","2012-02-01","2012-02-02","2012-02-03","2012-02-04"),
  value = c(1:10)))
```

This is the fake data set.

Now I want to create a new variable called Val2 based on the following condition:

** Whether the date of each row is no "2012-01-02","2012-02-02".

To achieve this, I tried this

```
1.  f <- function(x){ 
test <- ifelse(x %in% as.Date(c("2012-01-02","2012-02-02")) , TRUE, FALSE)
return(test)
}

DT[,Val2:= f(date)]
```

But all Val2 are true, which is obviously wrong.

As Roland pointed in my previous problem, I tried another one.

```
DT[, Val2:= sapply(date, function(x) x %in% as.Date(c("2012-01-02","2012-02-02")))]
```

Still not working with the following error:

**Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class ate?**

Also I tried to modified based on the error hints, but all failed.

Could you offer some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Your code to build `DT` is malformed.  Please fix it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew:) Already fixed

Comment: I beg to differ.  Paste from the question into your R interpreter.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I just copied the code from Rstudio, but when I copied back it doesn't work neither..Now hope the code is OK. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare to an object of the same class (IDate).  You also do not need to use `ifelse` to here, as it is just returning the value of `%in%`.

```
DT[,val2 := date %in% as.IDate(c("2012-01-02","2012-02-02"))]
> DT
     UID       date value  val2
 1: UID1 2012-01-01     1 FALSE
 2: UID1 2012-01-02     2  TRUE
 3: UID2 2012-01-03     3 FALSE
 4: UID2 2012-01-04     4 FALSE
 5: UID3 2012-01-05     5 FALSE
 6: UID3 2012-01-06     6 FALSE
 7: UID4 2012-02-01     7 FALSE
 8: UID4 2012-02-02     8  TRUE
 9: UID5 2012-02-03     9 FALSE
10: UID5 2012-02-04    10 FALSE
```

`DT`, prior to the addition of `val2`:

```
structure(list(UID = c("UID1", "UID1", "UID2", "UID2", "UID3", 
"UID3", "UID4", "UID4", "UID5", "UID5"), date = structure(c(15340L, 
15341L, 15342L, 15343L, 15344L, 15345L, 15371L, 15372L, 15373L, 
15374L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), value = 1:10), .Names = c("UID", 
"date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```