# Follow-up: Matching factor levels in R with shared unique row names

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

In follow-up to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064401/return-all-factor-levels-by-name-as-new-columns-from-a-three-column-data-table/30065089?noredirect=1#comment48245212_30065089). How do we use the dplyr or data.table package to match the factor levels appropriately with shared row names?

```
library(data.table)

(DT = data.table(a = LETTERS[c(1, 1:3, 8)], b = c(2, 4:7), 
                 c = as.factor(c("bob", "mary", "bob", "george", "alice")), key="a"))

#    a b      c
# 1: A 2    bob
# 2: A 4   mary
# 3: B 5    bob
# 4: C 6 george
# 5: H 7  alice
```

...and using @frank 's great answer:

```
uc <- sort(unique(as.character(DT$c)))
( DT[,(uc):=lapply(uc,function(x)ifelse(c==x,b,NA))][,c('b','c'):=NULL] )
```

Returns:

```
#   a alice bob george mary
# 1 A    NA   2     NA   NA
# 2 A    NA  NA     NA    4
# 3 B    NA   5     NA   NA
# 4 C    NA  NA      6   NA
# 5 H     7  NA     NA   NA
```

And the final question here is, how do we get the below output, where unique row names share level values returning NAs where empty elements remain?

```
       alice bob george mary
# 1 A    NA   2      NA    4
# 2 B    NA   5      NA   NA
# 3 C    NA   NA      6   NA
# 4 H     7   NA     NA   NA
```

Comment: if you wanted this result the whole time, you could have asked for it up front in your other question - `spread` is built for this, but instead you got answers that assumed you wanted the extra rows...

Comment: If you ever saw observations `A,2,bob` and `A,3,bob`, you'd be in trouble here. Is your data such that columns `a` and `b` are a key (with each combo appearing at most once)?

Comment: @Sam-Firke This is what I was aiming at intuitively, but noticed after the fact that I had left out a better part of the point. If you add a note to your other response with this as the outcome, I'll upvote it!

Comment: @Frank Not sure what you mean by "a and b are a key". The answer I was seeking related to having an arbitrary (i.e, >= 1 instance of each level to create unique columns)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant simply is it possible that you could have observations with `A,2,bob` and `A,3,bob`? If so, the value in the newly generated columns is indeterminate for row `A` column `bob` in the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(DT, c, b)
```

Comment: With **data.table** or **dplyr**?

Comment: @BobHopez If you're into dplyr, my understanding is tidyr is made to go with it.

Comment: You can consider tidyr as a dplyr cousin. They are meant to be used in tandem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an adaptation of the answer to the last question:

```
DT[,b:=as.integer(b)] # it's troublesome otherwise

uc <- sort(unique(as.character(DT$c)))
DT[,lapply(setNames(uc,uc),function(x)ifelse(x%in%c,b,NA_integer_)),by=a]
```

Result:

```
   a alice bob george mary
1: A    NA   2     NA    2
2: B    NA   5     NA   NA
3: C    NA  NA      6   NA
4: H     7  NA     NA   NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional support!