# how to get quick summary of count in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is a part of feature engineering that summarizes each ID depending on column called Col. The same preprocess will be applied to the testing set. Since the data set is large, data.table based solution may be more preferred.

Training Input:

```
ID   Col
A    M
A    M
A    M
B    K
B    M
```

Expected output for above training input:

```
ID   Col_M  Col_K
A    3      0      # A has 3 M in Col and 0 K in Col
B    1      1
```

Above is for processing training data. For testing dataset, if requires to mapping over Col_M, Col_K, meaning, if other value like S appearing in Col, it will be ignored.

Testing Input:

```
ID   Col 
C    M
C    S
```

Expected output for above testing input:

```
ID   Col_M  Col_K
C    1      0      # A has 1 M in Col and 0 K in Col. S value is ignored
```

Comment: can you add some paragraphs to explain what is shown? dummy code can help creating good answers :)

Comment: If you actually have R installed, and the data.table package as well, there's this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18881073/ Just define your own `inds` values.

Comment: @pachamaltese, yes, just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible `data.table` implementation could be first filter by `c("M", "K")`, then add these level (in case they aren't present like in your second case), then running `dcast` while specifying `drop = FALSE, fill = 0L` (for the cases when one of the desired levels is missing) while specifying `fun = length` (in order to count).

Testing on both data sets

```
library(data.table)

### First example
df <- fread("ID   Col
A    M
A    M
A    M
B    K
B    M")

dcast(df[Col %in% c("M", "K")], # Work only with c("M", "K")
      ID ~ factor(Col, levels = union(unique(Col), c("M", "K"))), # Add missing levels
      drop = FALSE, # Keep missing levels in output
      fill = 0L, # Fill missing values with zeroes instead of NAs
      fun = length) # Count. you can also specify 'value.var'

#    ID M K
# 1:  A 3 0
# 2:  B 1 1

### Second example
df <- fread("ID   Col 
C    M
C    S")

dcast(df[Col %in% c("M", "K")], 
  ID ~ factor(Col, levels = union(unique(Col), c("M", "K"))), 
  drop = FALSE,
  fill = 0L,
  fun = length)

#    ID M K
# 1:  C 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and detailed explanation. The solution is general enough. Are you able to attend above two extensions?

Comment: You are transforming this into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions). You can't add new edits after getting an answer. Adding a window function a whole new question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. please find the new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688711/how-to-get-quick-summary-in-data-table-with-a-look-back-window

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how big is your data and how flexible the expected code should be, but I have this:

```
zz = '
ID   Col
A    M
A    M
A    M
B    K
B    M
'

df <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)
col = as.data.frame(table(df))

out <- reshape(col, idvar = "ID",
               timevar = "Col", direction = "wide")
out
```

which gives you:

```
> out
  ID Freq.K Freq.M
1  A      0      3
2  B      1      1
```

And for the second data frame:

```
yy = '
ID   Col
C    M
C    S
'

df1 <- read.table(text = yy, header = TRUE)
col1 = as.data.frame(table(df1))

out1 <- reshape(col1, idvar = "ID",
               timevar = "Col", direction = "wide")
out1
```

you get:

```
> out1
  ID Freq.M Freq.S
1  C      1      1
```

Then just merge them together and delete the redundant:

```
ss = merge(out1, out, all.y = T, all.x = T)
ss
  ID Freq.M Freq.S Freq.K
1  C      1      1     NA
2  A      3     NA      0
3  B      1     NA      1
```

Comment: Their desired output doesn't include `S` column.

Comment: That's right. I was waiting for a comment if this was OK or not, Then I'd edit the last bit of the code to get rid off `S` col and sub `NAs` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(data.table)
> dt=NULL
> dt$ID=c("A","A","A","B","B")
> dt$Col=c("M","M","M","K","M")
> dt=data.frame(dt)
> dt=data.table(dt)
> dt
   ID Col
1:  A   M
2:  A   M
3:  A   M
4:  B   K
5:  B   M


> a=dt[Col=="M",sum(.N),ID]
> b=dt[Col=="K",sum(.N),ID]
> a
   ID V1
1:  A  3
2:  B  1
> b
   ID V1
1:  B  1
> setkey(a,ID)
> setkey(b,ID)

> m=b[a]
> m
   ID V1 i.V1
1:  A NA    3
2:  B  1    1
> names(m)=c("ID","Col_K","Col_M")
> m
   ID Col_K Col_M
1:  A    NA     3
2:  B     1     1
```

Comment: used data.table code for selection and merging due to big data concerns

Comment: it should since selection is only for M and K, prior to merge

Comment: There is no K in the second example but you still need to have it in the output

Comment: Col_K would be NA

Comment: @AjayOhri, thanks for the elegant solution. Can you add one more step if percentage between Col_K, Col_M is required? Thanks!