# How to get quick summary in data.table with a look-back window?

Tags: r, data.table

This question is an extension based on [how to get quick summary of count in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666715/how-to-get-quick-summary-of-count-in-data-table/44668535?noredirect=1#comment76348123_44668535).

Similarly, this is a part of feature engineering that summarizes each ID depending on column called Col *by looking back with certain time window*. The same preprocess will be applied to the testing set. Since the data set is large, data.table based solution may be more preferred.

### 1. summerize on a variable and value with a look-back window

Training Input:

```
ID   Time        Col   Count 
A    2017-06-05   M      1
A    2017-06-02   M      1
A    2017-06-03   M      1
B    2017-06-02   K      1
B    2017-06-01   M      4
```

By applying two days looking back, we have:

```
ID   Time          Time-2D   Col   Count
A    2017-06-05   2017-06-03   M      1   #Time-2D by moving time two days back
A    2017-06-02   2017-05-31   M      1
A    2017-06-03   2017-06-01   M      1
B    2017-06-02   2017-05-31   K      1
B    2017-06-01   2017-05-30   M      4
```

Expected output (count):

```
ID   Time          Time-2D   Col_M    Col_K
A    2017-06-05   2017-06-03   1      0     #from 2017-06-03 to 2017-06-05, for user A, there are 0 (sum(count)) of K and 1 (sum(count)) of M. 
A    2017-06-02   2017-05-31   1      0
A    2017-06-03   2017-06-01   2      0     # 2 is because from 06-01 to 06-03, there is two rows in the first table (A    2017-06-02   M      1; A    2017-06-03   M      1) that the count summarization on M is 2. 
B    2017-06-02   2017-05-31   0      1
B    2017-06-01   2017-05-30   4      0
```

### 2. Calculate ratio

Based on above table, 
Expected output (ratio):

```
ID   Time          Time-2D   Col_M    Col_K
A    2017-06-05   2017-06-03   1      0     # 1/sum(1+0)
A    2017-06-02   2017-05-31   1      0
A    2017-06-03   2017-06-01   1      0     #2/sum(2+0)
B    2017-06-02   2017-05-31   0      1
B    2017-06-01   2017-05-30   1      0     # 4/sum(4+0)
```

Above is for processing training data. For testing dataset, if requires to mapping over Col_M, Col_K, meaning, if other value like S appearing in Col, it will be ignored.

Comment: maybe in your step 1, the expected output is wrong. not 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your request. You seem to care about the order of the observations regardless if, for instance, the second observations `Time` is prior to the first observations `Time`. That doesn't make much sense, but here is a quit efficient data.table solution in order to achieve this. This is basically does a *non-equi* join by `ID`, `Col`, Both `Time` columns *and* the row index (which is basically the appearance order). Afterwards, it just `dcast` to convert from long to wide (like in your previous question). Note that the result is ordered by the dates, but I've kept the `rowindx` variable, so you can reorder it back using `setorder`. Also, I'll keep the ratio calc to you as this is very basic (hint - *Don't* use loops, it is a fully vectorized one liner)

```
library(data.table) #v1.10.4+

## Read the data
DT <- fread("ID   Time        Col   Count 
A    2017-06-05   M      1
A    2017-06-02   M      1
A    2017-06-03   M      1
B    2017-06-02   K      1
B    2017-06-01   M      4")

## Prepare the variables we need for the join
DT[, Time := as.IDate(Time)]
DT[, Time_2D := Time - 2L]
DT[, rowindx := .I]

## Non-equi join, sum `Count` by each join
DT2 <- DT[DT, 
          sum(Count), 
          on = .(ID, Col, rowindx <= rowindx, Time <= Time, Time >= Time_2D),
          by = .EACHI]

## Fix column names (a known issue)
setnames(DT2, make.unique(names(DT2)))

## Long to wide (You can reorder back using `rowindx` and `setorder` function)
dcast(DT2, ID + Time + Time.1 + rowindx ~ Col, value.var = "V1", fill = 0)
#    ID       Time     Time.1 rowindx K M
# 1:  A 2017-06-02 2017-05-31       2 0 1
# 2:  A 2017-06-03 2017-06-01       3 0 2
# 3:  A 2017-06-05 2017-06-03       1 0 1
# 4:  B 2017-06-01 2017-05-30       5 0 4
# 5:  B 2017-06-02 2017-05-31       4 1 0
```

Comment: have a quick question. do you know how to take column-wised sum for a list of columns? i.e., ```DT2 <- DT[DT, 
          sum(Count), 
          on = .(ID, Col, rowindx <= rowindx, Time <= Time, Time >= Time_2D),
          by = .EACHI]```, we have ```count``` column, as well as other columns.

Comment: Yes, Like you would always do in data.table. For instance, if you also have `Count2` and `Count3` cols, you could simply do: `DT2 <- DT[DT, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("Count", "Count2", "Count3"),on = .(ID, Col, rowindx <= rowindx, Time <= Time, Time >= Time_2D), by = .EACHI]`

Comment: thanks. it works. I tried previously with .SDcols, however, it has conflix with keyby. Is there any difference between ```by=.EACHI``` and ```keyby=.EACHI```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "*conflix*". The difference between `by` and `keyby` is that `by` leaves the result unordered while `keyby` adds a key (according to the specified columns) and as a result, orders the whole data by the specified columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
dt <- fread("ID   Time          Time-2D   Col   Count
        A    2017-06-05   2017-06-03   M      1   
        A    2017-06-02   2017-05-31   M      1
        A    2017-06-03   2017-06-01   M      1
        B    2017-06-02   2017-05-31   K      1
        B    2017-06-01   2017-05-30   M      4") 
dt1 <- dcast(dt, ID+Time+`Time-2D`~Col, value.var = c("Count"))
dt1[, K := ifelse(is.na(K), 0, K)]
dt1[, M := ifelse(is.na(M), 0, M)]

   ID       Time    Time-2D K M
1:  A 2017-06-02 2017-05-31 0 1
2:  A 2017-06-03 2017-06-01 0 1
3:  A 2017-06-05 2017-06-03 0 1
4:  B 2017-06-01 2017-05-30 0 4
5:  B 2017-06-02 2017-05-31 1 0

dt1[, Col_K := K/(K+M)]
dt1[, Col_M := M/(K+M)]

    ID       Time    Time-2D K M Col_K Col_M
1:  A 2017-06-02 2017-05-31 0 1     0     1
2:  A 2017-06-03 2017-06-01 0 1     0     1
3:  A 2017-06-05 2017-06-03 0 1     0     1
4:  B 2017-06-01 2017-05-30 0 4     0     1
5:  B 2017-06-02 2017-05-31 1 0     1     0
```

Maybe you can combine last 2 lines. something like

```
dt1[, `:=`()]
```

Comment: I think the aggregation and ratio steps are missing.

Comment: Actually, the expected output you post above not contain aggregation and ratio. Or maybe I misunderstand your porblem. can u explain more and add in your question?

Comment: explain more about your step 2

Comment: it's explained in the comment. e.g., # 4/sum(4+0), this mean 4/4=1

Comment: I edit it. maybe in your step 1, the expected output is wrong. not 2?

Comment: it's not a typo. just added explanation about it.

Comment: Actually, I cannot understand `# 2 is because from 06-01 to 06-03, there is two M occurs in A. ` Maybe you need to explaim more and describe clearly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147446/discussion-between-happycoding-and-peter-chen).