# Convert a columns into separate columns in wide format in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to convert the "FRUITS" column into separate columns ("Apple" and "Banana") in wide format.

```
  Gender  AgeGroup              EAT           FRUITS 
1 Female 30yr_39yr              Yes             Apple           
2 Female 20yr_29yr              Yes             Apple              
3 Female 70yr_80yr              Yes             Apple             
4   Male 50yr_59yr              Yes             Banana              
5 Female 40yr_49yr              Yes             Apple                  
6 Female 70yr_80yr              Yes             Apple
```

how to convert FRUITS column into:

```
  Gender AgeGroup       EAT  Apple      Banana 
1 Female 30yr_39yr      Yes  TRUE      FALSE
2 Female 20yr_29yr      Yes  TRUE      FALSE
3 Female 70yr_80yr      Yes  TRUE      FALSE
4   Male 50yr_59yr      Yes  FALSE     TRUE
5 Female 40yr_49yr      Yes  TRUE      FALSE
6 Female 70yr_80yr      Yes  TRUE      FALSE
```

Here is the dataframe I used:

```
data.frame(
  Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female"),
  AgeGroup = c("30yr_39yr", "20yr_29yr", "70yr_80yr", "50yr_59yr", "40yr_49yr", "70yr_80yr"),
  EAT = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
  FRUITS = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple")
)
```

Comment: If binary, you can hardcode `x$Apple = ifelse(x$FRUITS == "Apple", TRUE, FALSE); x$Banana = !x$Apple`

Comment: for a data.table solution look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881073/creating-dummy-variables-in-r-data-table)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
df[c("Apple", "Banana")] <- list(df$FRUITS == "Apple", df$FRUITS == "Banana")

#   Gender  AgeGroup EAT FRUITS Apple Banana
# 1 Female 30yr_39yr Yes  Apple  TRUE  FALSE
# 2 Female 20yr_29yr Yes  Apple  TRUE  FALSE
# 3 Female 70yr_80yr Yes  Apple  TRUE  FALSE
# 4   Male 50yr_59yr Yes Banana FALSE   TRUE
# 5 Female 40yr_49yr Yes  Apple  TRUE  FALSE
# 6 Female 70yr_80yr Yes  Apple  TRUE  FALSE
```

To generalise to more value you could use:

```
cols <- c("Apple", "Banana")
df[cols] <- lapply(cols, \(x) df$FRUITS == x)
```

Answer (score 7):

To reshape to wide using `tidyr::pivot_wider` you have to add a value column to your dataset and a column with a unique id for each row:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female"),
  AgeGroup = c("30yr_39yr", "20yr_29yr", "70yr_80yr", "50yr_59yr", "40yr_49yr", "70yr_80yr"),
  EAT = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
  FRUITS = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple")
)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df |>
  mutate(
    value = TRUE,
    id = row_number()
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = FRUITS,
    values_from = value, values_fill = FALSE
  ) |>
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   Gender AgeGroup  EAT   Apple Banana
#>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <lgl> <lgl> 
#> 1 Female 30yr_39yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
#> 2 Female 20yr_29yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
#> 3 Female 70yr_80yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
#> 4 Male   50yr_59yr Yes   FALSE TRUE  
#> 5 Female 40yr_49yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
#> 6 Female 70yr_80yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE
```

Comment: Congrats on 100k!

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Would never have made it this far without the support and shared knowledge of the R and SO community. (:

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach using `unnest_wider()`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(FRUITS = map(FRUITS, ~ set_names(levels(factor(FRUITS)) == .x, levels(factor(FRUITS))))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(FRUITS)

Gender AgeGroup  EAT   Apple Banana
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <lgl> <lgl> 
1 Female 30yr_39yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
2 Female 20yr_29yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
3 Female 70yr_80yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
4 Male   50yr_59yr Yes   FALSE TRUE  
5 Female 40yr_49yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
6 Female 70yr_80yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE
```

Here is a slightly adapted version using `values_fn`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = FRUITS, values_from = FRUITS, 
              values_fn = list(FRUITS = ~length(.x) > 0), 
              values_fill = FALSE) %>% 
  select(-row_id)
```

```
 Gender AgeGroup  EAT   Apple Banana
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <lgl> <lgl> 
1 Female 30yr_39yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
2 Female 20yr_29yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
3 Female 70yr_80yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
4 Male   50yr_59yr Yes   FALSE TRUE  
5 Female 40yr_49yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE 
6 Female 70yr_80yr Yes   TRUE  FALSE
```

For this specific example and without generalizability

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(Apple = FRUITS == "Apple", Banana = FRUITS == "Banana")
```

Comment: `list(FRUITS = ~length(.x) > 0)` can be replaced with the much simpler `~ TRUE`

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

The original answer with pivot_wider is WRONG, I removed it. As suggested by @stefan in the comments, it dropped a row.
A proper solution would include a preliminary step to add an index column, as already shown in @TarJae's answer, to which I should only add the simplification `values_fn = ~ TRUE`.
The dummy_cols suggestion stands as a valid alternative

If a one-hot encoding/dummy presentation of values is OK (1s and 0s instead of logical), `fastDummies::dummy_cols` is nice too:

```
library(fastDummies)
df |> 
    dummy_cols('FRUITS',
               remove_selected_columns = TRUE,
               omit_colname_prefix = TRUE)

  Gender  AgeGroup EAT Apple Banana
1 Female 30yr_39yr Yes     1      0
2 Female 20yr_29yr Yes     1      0
3 Female 70yr_80yr Yes     1      0
4   Male 50yr_59yr Yes     0      1
5 Female 40yr_49yr Yes     1      0
6 Female 70yr_80yr Yes     1      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two more:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  cbind(model.matrix(~ FRUITS + 0, .) == 1)
```

```
library(nnet)
df %>% cbind(class.ind(.$FRUITS) == 1)
```

Comment: Nice additions. `model.matrix` is a good , option. O did nota know `cnnet::class.ind`. +1