# Transforming a Dataframe into a matrix keeping one column as attribute

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Destination    User     User_Price 
     A          a           5
     A          b           4
     B          c           6
     B          a           5
     C          b           4
     C          d           7
```

I want to convert this into a matrix that shows what destination a user has hit that looks like this:

```
   User    User_Price    A    B    C    
    a          5         1    1    0
    b          4         1    0    1
    c          6         0    1    0
    d          7         0    0    1
```

Comment: Essentially `table(foo[c("User", "Destination")])` if you are just looking to use this as a summary table.

Comment: Relevant question - with relevant links attached to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659128/how-to-use-cast-or-another-function-to-create-a-binary-table-in-r/11659636

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way with the `dplyr` and `tidyr` package would be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

count(foo, User, User_Price, Destination) %>%
spread(key = Destination, value = n, fill = 0)

#    User User_Price     A     B     C
#  (fctr)      (int) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1      a          5     1     1     0
#2      b          4     1     0     1
#3      c          6     0     1     0
#4      d          7     0     0     1
```

If you need a matrix, you can convert this outcome (data frame) to matrix.

**DATA**

```
foo <- structure(list(Destination = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), User = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
User_Price = c(5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 7L)), .Names = c("Destination", 
"User", "User_Price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(foo),User + User_Price ~ Destination, length, value.var="Destination")
#   User User_Price A B C
#1:    a          5 1 1 0
#2:    b          4 1 0 1
#3:    c          6 0 1 0
#4:    d          7 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks very similar to a normal reshaping operation, except with some idiosyncrasies that require several lines of code to achieve in base R.

First, for reference and comparison purposes, here's what the minimalist `reshape()` call produces:

```
df <- data.frame(Destination=c('A','A','B','B','C','C'),User=c('a','b','c','a','b','d'),User_Price=c(5L,4L,6L,5L,4L,7L),stringsAsFactors=F);
reshape(df,dir='w',idvar='User',timevar='Destination');
##   User User_Price.A User_Price.B User_Price.C
## 1    a            5            5           NA
## 2    b            4           NA            4
## 3    c           NA            6           NA
## 6    d           NA           NA            7
```

Clearly there are several issues that must be addressed before we can arrive at the required output:

- We must compute the required singular `User_Price` column from the multiple widened columns.
- We must replace NA prices with 0.
- We must replace non-NA prices with 1.
- We must fix the column names to omit the `User_Price.` prefix.

Here's a complete solution, using `df` from above:

```
res <- reshape(df,dir='w',idvar='User',timevar='Destination');
pre <- '^User_Price\\.';
cis <- grep(pre,names(res));
res$User_Price <- do.call(pmax,c(res[cis],na.rm=T));
names(res)[cis] <- sub(pre,'',names(res)[cis]);
nas <- is.na(res[cis]);
res[cis][nas] <- 0;
res[cis][!nas] <- 1;
res;
  User A B C User_Price
1    a 1 1 0          5
2    b 1 0 1          4
3    c 0 1 0          6
6    d 0 0 1          7
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark);
library(dplyr);
library(tidyr);
library(data.table);

bgoldst <- function(df) { res <- reshape(df,dir='w',idvar='User',timevar='Destination'); pre <- '^User_Price\\.'; cis <- grep(pre,names(res)); res$User_Price <- do.call(pmax,c(res[cis],na.rm=T)); names(res)[cis] <- sub(pre,'',names(res)[cis]); nas <- is.na(res[cis]); res[cis][nas] <- 0; res[cis][!nas] <- 1; res; };
thelatemail <- function(df) { x <- table(df[,c('User','Destination')]); data.frame(User=rownames(x),User_Price=df[match(rownames(x),df$User),'User_Price'],unclass(x)); };
jazzurro <- function(foo) { count(foo, User, User_Price, Destination) %>% spread(key = Destination, value = n, fill = 0); };
akrun <- function(foo) dcast(setDT(foo),User + User_Price ~ Destination, length, value.var="Destination");
```

---

```
## OP's test case
df <- data.frame(Destination=c('A','A','B','B','C','C'),User=c('a','b','c','a','b','d'),User_Price=c(5L,4L,6L,5L,4L,7L));
dt <- as.data.table(df);

ex <- bgoldst(df); o <- names(ex); us <- ex$User;
all.equal(ex,thelatemail(df)[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(ex,jazzurro(df)[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(ex,as.data.frame(akrun(dt))[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(df),thelatemail(df),jazzurro(df),akrun(dt));
## Unit: microseconds
##             expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
##      bgoldst(df) 1767.488 1897.281 2021.7741 1943.894 2035.6260 5227.196   100
##  thelatemail(df)  473.412  536.063  574.4233  578.186  608.1225  738.129   100
##     jazzurro(df) 2707.468 2914.666 3145.7258 3032.270 3160.3515 5677.514   100
##        akrun(dt) 4403.964 4721.069 5026.5023 4875.238 5028.1230 7703.303   100
```

---

```
## scale test
set.seed(1L);
ND <- 1e3L; NU <- 1e3L; NR <- 1e4L;
dests <- sample(make.unique(rep(LETTERS,len=ND)),NR,T);
us <- make.unique(rep(letters,len=NU));
users <- ave(dests,dests,FUN=function(x) sample(us,length(x)));
prices <- ave(seq_along(users),users,FUN=function(x) rep(sample(1:9,1L),len=length(x)));
df <- data.frame(Destination=dests,User=users,User_Price=prices);
dt <- as.data.table(df);

ex <- bgoldst(df); o <- names(ex); us <- ex$User;
all.equal(ex,thelatemail(df)[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(ex,jazzurro(df)[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(ex,as.data.frame(akrun(dt))[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(df),thelatemail(df),jazzurro(df),akrun(dt),times=10L);
## Unit: milliseconds
##             expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
##      bgoldst(df) 1381.46461 1418.13922 1445.20568 1437.82683 1474.79075 1538.37153    10
##  thelatemail(df)   31.84727   37.56498   57.47417   44.54106   82.39749   92.63933    10
##     jazzurro(df)   79.18924   91.20755  117.20360  126.22693  136.13885  168.26623    10
##        akrun(dt)   52.06625   59.02158   79.59568   70.09136  106.93019  130.31208    10
```

---

```
## scale test 2
set.seed(1L);
ND <- 1e4L; NU <- 1e4L; NR <- 1e6L;
dests <- sample(make.unique(rep(LETTERS,len=ND)),NR,T);
us <- make.unique(rep(letters,len=NU));
users <- ave(dests,dests,FUN=function(x) sample(us,length(x)));
prices <- ave(seq_along(users),users,FUN=function(x) rep(sample(1:9,1L),len=length(x)));
df <- data.frame(Destination=dests,User=users,User_Price=prices);
dt <- as.data.table(df);

ex <- bgoldst(df); o <- names(ex); us <- ex$User;
all.equal(ex,thelatemail(df)[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(ex,jazzurro(df)[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(ex,as.data.frame(akrun(dt))[us,o],check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(df),thelatemail(df),jazzurro(df),akrun(dt),times=1L);
## Unit: seconds
##             expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
##      bgoldst(df) 485.849043 485.849043 485.849043 485.849043 485.849043 485.849043     1
##  thelatemail(df)   3.377981   3.377981   3.377981   3.377981   3.377981   3.377981     1
##     jazzurro(df)  12.858542  12.858542  12.858542  12.858542  12.858542  12.858542     1
##        akrun(dt)   4.132785   4.132785   4.132785   4.132785   4.132785   4.132785     1
```

Comment: I am not sure `table` works that efficient when the number of rows increases to around 1e7 or so.

Comment: @akrun I added a benchmark with 1e6 rows. I tried 1e7 but got the error `Error in table(df[, c("User", "Destination")]) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements` when running `thelatemail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same is using dcast.

> a <- dcast(foo,User + User_Price ~ Destination,fill=0)

Later change the values for the Destination columns